# Python json dumps syntax error when appending list of dict

Tags: python, json

I got two functions that return a list of dictionary and i'm trying to get json to encode it, it works when i try doing it with my first function, but now i'm appending second function with a syntax error of `": expected"`. I will eventually be appending total of 7 functions that each output a list of dict. Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

```
import dmidecode
import simplejson as json

def get_bios_specs():
    BIOSdict = {}
    BIOSlist = []
    for v in dmidecode.bios().values():
        if type(v) == dict and v['dmi_type'] == 0:
            BIOSdict["Name"] = str((v['data']['Vendor']))
            BIOSdict["Description"] = str((v['data']['Vendor']))
            BIOSdict["BuildNumber"] = str((v['data']['Version']))
            BIOSdict["SoftwareElementID"] = str((v['data']['BIOS Revision']))
            BIOSdict["primaryBIOS"] = "True"

            BIOSlist.append(BIOSdict)
    return BIOSlist

def get_board_specs():
    MOBOdict = {}
    MOBOlist = []
    for v in dmidecode.baseboard().values():
        if type(v) == dict and v['dmi_type'] == 2:
           MOBOdict["Manufacturer"] =  str(v['data']['Manufacturer'])
           MOBOdict["Model"] = str(v['data']['Product Name'])

           MOBOlist.append(MOBOdict)
    return MOBOlist


def get_json_dumps():
    jsonOBJ = json

    #Syntax error is here, i can't use comma to continue adding more, nor + to append.
    return  jsonOBJ.dumps({'HardwareSpec':{'BIOS': get_bios_specs()},{'Motherboard': get_board_specs()}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple items within your nested dictionary.

```
jsonOBJ.dumps({
    'HardwareSpec': {
        'BIOS': get_bios_specs(),
        'Motherboard': get_board_specs()
     }
})
```

And if you want multiple `BIOS` items or `Motherboard` items, just use a list.

```
...
     'HardwareSpec': {
        'BIOS': [
            get_bios_specs(),
            get_uefi_specs()
        ]
        ...
     }
```

Comment: Thanks but this gives me the format of "Json -> HardwareSpec -> 0 - BIOS -> ... , 1 - Motherboard -> ..."  I'm looking for the output  "Json -> HardwareSpec ->  BIOS - 0 -> ... , Motherboard  - 0 -> ...", if that even make sense..

Comment: @Dayan: Sure it does. I edited the answer to give an example.

Comment: Thank you, great examples, I like the 2nd one!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more convenient lookup of specs, you can just embed a dict:

```
jsonOBJ.dumps({'HardwareSpec':{'BIOS': get_bios_specs(), 
  'Motherboard': get_board_specs()
  }
})
```